# Cant access object id in view

Tags: django

URLdispatch:

```
url(r'^comment/(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/(?P<comment_pk>)\d+$', comment_delete, name='comment_delete')
```

view function:

```
def comment_delete(request, gslug, slug, comment_pk):
```

comment_pk's value is blank even though I am seeing the proper id number in the link in the template

template url tag

```
{% url 'comment_delete' group_profile.slug discussion.slug comment.pk %}
```

Comment: Move the `\d+` inside the `(?P<comment_pk)`.

Comment: Thank you, lol I came back to post that I had found it